# Executing WHERE IN using bindparameters in Sqlalchemy/Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I try to do a `SELECT ... WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` efficiently using Sqlalchemy with Postges.

If I do a simple select:

```
s.query(Model).filter(Model.id.in_([1,2,3])).all()
```

Sqlalchemy runs this query:

```
SELECT model.id AS model_id FROM model 
WHERE model.id IN (%(id_1)s, %(id_2)s, %(id_3)s)
{'id_1': 1, 'id_2': 2, 'id_3': 3}
```

When the array gets longer this is not efficient. Also this does not work with baked queries.

Knowing that Postgres supports tuples as parameters, I tried to put in my Array/Tuple directly into the parameter section by using a bind parameter:

```
s.query(Model)
 .filter(Model.id.in_(bindparam('my_tuple')))
 .params(my_tuple=(1,2,3)).all()
```

Unfortunately Sqlalchemy does not accept `bindparam` in an `in_`:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: 
    in_() accepts either a list of expressions or a selectable:
        BindParameter('my_tuple', None, type_=NullType())
```

So I tried to trick Sqlalchemy somehow to accept a `bindparam`.
Extending the `BindParam` class I was able to do so:

```
class TupleBindParameter(BindParameter, Selectable):
    pass

s.query(Model)
 .filter(Model.id.in_(TupleBindParameter('my_tuple')))
 .params(my_tuple=(1,2,3)).all()
```

Now I get what I wanted:

```
SELECT model.id AS model_id FROM model 
WHERE model.id IN %(my_tuple)s
{'my_tuple': (1, 2, 3)}
```

This solution seems somehow hacky to me. Is there an official way to get Sqlalchemy do do the same?

--

The setup to reproduce my examples is very simple:

```
Base = declarative_base()    
class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'model'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    def __init__(self, id): self.id = id

engine = create_engine('postgres://x:x@localhost/x')    
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s = Session()
s.add_all([Model(1), Model(2), Model(4)])
s.commit()
```

Comment: Have you profiled that this actually makes the query more efficient?

Comment: @univerio: I tested it. It does make a difference. I used 1000 queries with an array of 1000 elements. SimpleVersion = 40s; Bindparams=10s. You also need the bindparams to use a bakery. If you have a query with many joins, the bakery makes an enormous difference. In my case it was factor 40.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `op('IN')`

```
s.query(Model)
 .filter(Model.id.op('IN')(bindparam('my_tuple')))
 .params(my_tuple=(1,2,3)).all()
```

see [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3574)

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks